# Remove faded/ignored-tag questions from results

Tags: discussion, ignored-tags

Is there any way to have questions with ignored tags not show up in question lists at all? I've got a small handful of ignored tags (about half a dozen), but I find that the number of faded questions in e.g. the "Unanswered" questions list is large and distracting. On Stack Overflow, ignoring PHP can result in half the questions on any given page being faded. I'm ignoring them because I don't want to see them at all, while just fading them out actually serves to highlight them in a distracting way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into [your account preferences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current), scroll all the way down to the "ignored tags" section, and change the radio button to

> Hide questions in your ignored tags

The direct link to *your* preferences is https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/209615